# Could adding explicit database transactions to an app massively hurt performance?

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions

I have an old app running on SQL Server (but I suspect the concept I'm asking about applies to most/all major DBs) that got re-written. Aside from the fact that a lot of the UI changes and more modular backend code resulted in different queries, one of the major changes is that the old code used zero explicit transactions.

Yeah, as in if an error happened, you'd be left with orphan records and such. The new app has corrected that, using transactions when there are multiple inserts/updates. That seems to be a no-brainer, but we're finding that we're getting a lot of complaints about performance, particularly from clients that have more data (each client has their own separate DB). Am I correct in assuming that, given the transactions, there's a lot more room for resources to be waiting on locks, which could then drastically hurt performance?

Btw, another major difference is that the old app relied on stored procedures to a point, whereas the new app does not use them at all. I'm throwing this in here just in case, but I'm really under the impression that transactions being a problem is more likely, especially given the complexity of the queries in the system (tons of queries with lots of joins, subqueries in the SELECT clause, etc.)

Also, it's worth noting we're not talking huge databases/tables. Each client has their own database and clients complaining have tables with a few million records at worse, but not billions/trillions of records or anything like that. While some new queries have been introduced and some have changed, the majority of queries are the same as in the old system, sometimes just running outside of a stored proc when before they were inside of one. Also, a lot of the more complicated queries have been checked and when run on their own, they're fast.

Comment: This would have to be considered on a case by case basis, otherwise your question is subject to a lot of opinion. Consider doing some performance monitoring on the transactions that users are complaining about. If you cannot reproduce the slowdowns in your environment, consider adding some logging at the beginning and end of the sections of code in question to identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Just to be clear, I realize that nobody can tell me if that's the definite cause of performance problems in my specific case, I just want to know if that's even a possibility, or if adding explicit transactions couldn't possibly lead to this kind of degradation.

Comment: So you have completely different app that works with database in completely different way, you got "tons of queries" that were turned from SPs into adhocs, you measured none, can't even say are there writes or reads performing slow and... blame transactions?

Comment: @Ivan There are some different queries, but majority are the same as before. The most complex ones have been measured and are running fine on their own, which is why I suspect that if transactions can make locking worse, everything working together under load could be affected. I'm not blaming transactions, I'm asking if it's possible for them to cause this kind of slowdown or not. Maybe you're a DBA and know all about SQL Server and how to check performance, but not everybody does, my core competencies lie elsewhere but I've nonetheless been tasked to look into this.

Comment: Set up a performance data warehouse and start analyzing the data.And yes, that is a function in SQL Server for a long time now.

Comment: @Rocket04, no offense. All I did is made a hint to you. But you continue repeating same things and don't even listen to yourself. Why are you thinking of transactions? You measured what to think so? You are reading tea leaves. You should stop trying to guess a magic button or any option **rocket mode=on**, start monitoring and debugging your app. Again, you developed completely new product with new UI and data layer. So, what is slow? You are getting a lot of complaints about performance. Performance of what? Are you sure that this is DB, not UI, ORM?

Comment: google for scripts for monitoring wait stats, dig into it, identify what is your server waiting for. Run profiler and watch what's going on under certain spid. Perhaps you forgot to enable caching framework in your app. _" a lot of the more complicated queries have been checked and when run on their own, they're fast."_ - this does not mean that execution plan of every of those queries is good. Probably server is able to perform 'em fast only when no one else is on the server.

Comment: @Ivan No offense taken, but understand where I'm coming from. It's the real world, I report to higher ups, they want answers and I have the unenviable position of having to provide them. I know there are monitoring tools that can be setup. I have done what is within the limitations of my current skillset, there's more to be checked on and we're likely going to get consultants to do a more thorough analysis. Which is why I'm asking simply about a possibility, I'm not asking for a magic solution.

Comment: Even if it was transactions, it wouldn't be a magic solution. What could I do, remove them? Then I have no data integrity. So if transactions are at the heart of it, it's as much of a pain in the ass as anything else. I know I can google until I'm blue in the face, I just don't have the time right now, sadly. Neither do I have the luxury of telling people that I'm not the best person to even be looking into this.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1949/sql-server-sysdmoswaitstats-dmv-queries/

Comment: Ivan, if you formulate your comments plus the helpful link you provided as an answer, I'll mark it as the best answer, seeing as nobody else has replied and yours were the most useful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by setting up a series of jobs/procs packaged as dbWarden. This allowed us to identify that there was a lot of blocking happening in certain cases. Once we figure that out, we made adjustments to avoid the blocking, including making certain operations read/write to different DBs, adjusting indexes, and making some operations query different data stores (ElasticSearch).